# react-native-image-picker response.uri is undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

In my react-native app, I using `react-native-image-picker` to pick image from camera or gallery. But the `resource.uri` returned in `undefined` in both `launchCamera` and `launchImageLibrary`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my [github repo](https://github.com/PavithraSutantraa/sellerApp) of a basic build of the react-native app. The image picker code is in addProductScreen.js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I saw your problem and I have a solution for you.
the response is a JSON object that contains an array called assets
so you can access your image url by using this.

> `response.assets[0].uri`

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me too. I did thumsUp for your answer.

Comment: @shammi, do you know if this is something new that "assets" is returned in the response? :-)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, and I can explain it so here is why!

`response` is a JSON object that contains an array called `assets`.

To access the first element of the array use `.assets[0]`, then you can access the `.uri`, `.fileName`, etc..

```json
{
  //response.uri is looking for the uri right here instead of inside assets[]
  "assets": [
    {
      "fileName": "yourImage.jpg",
      "fileSize": 123,
      "height": 123,
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "uri": "yourImage.jpg",
      "width": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers above, this worked for:

```js
const handleSelectImage = () => {
    const options = {
      noData: true,
      mediaType: 'photo' as const
    }
    launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      if (response.assets) {
        const imageAssetsArray = response.assets[0].uri
        setImageState(imageAssetsArray)
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was scratching my head with this as well.  I wrote a function to test what object was being returned from my photo selection:

```
    launchCamera(options, (response) => {
      if (response.assets && response.assets?.length !== 0) {
        setFilePath(response.assets[0].uri)
        console.log('ASSET OBJECT FOUND: ', response.assets[0].uri)
        return
      } else if (response.uri) {
        setFilePath(response.uri)
        console.log('NO ASSET OBJECT FOUND: ', response.uri)
        return
      } else if (response.didCancel) {
        return
      } else if (response.errorCode === 'camera_unavailable') {
        setNoCameraFound(true)
        return
      } else {
        setNeedsCameraAccess(true)
        return
      }
    })
```

When using my iPhone the `Asset` object was undefined, but on my Android it was there. If you're using TypeScript, it complains about `response.uri` unless you add that value to `types.d.ts`

```
    didCancel?: boolean;
    errorCode?: ErrorCode;
    errorMessage?: string;
    assets?: Asset[];
    uri?: string;
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue with the undefined `Asset` object? I seem to have the same problem on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

THIS SOLUTION BY @ shammi worked for me....
Be sure to log the result the console to the terminal before trying to use it just to make sure its in the expected format.

response.assets[0].uri